# Compositum of all Galois extensions of prime power degree

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$ a field of characteristic $\not =p$ prime, and $\mathbb{K}_p$ the compositum of all the Galois extensions of $\mathbb{K}$ whose degree is a power of $p$.

I have to prove that for every finite extension $\mathbb{K}\subseteq\mathbb{L}\subseteq\mathbb{K}_p$, the degree of $\mathbb{L}$ over $\mathbb{K}$ is a power of $p$.

My conjecture is that every Galois finite extension of $\mathbb{K}$ laying under $\mathbb{K}_p$ has this property, and then the thesis would follow from the multiplicativity of degrees. But I don't know how to prove this (or the thesis itself) because I have no clue at all about whar $\mathbb{K}_p$ looks like.

Do you have any hint or idea? I've been thinking about this problem for days but I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a finite set of generators for $L/K$. (In fact, a single generator will suffice: why?) Each of these lives in $K_p$, which means it lives in a compositum of finitely many Galois extensions of $p$-power degree.

Then $L$ lives in a sub-extension of a finite compositum of $p$-power extensions.

We want to show that $L$ has $p$-power degree. It will suffice to show that the Galois closure of $L$ is of $p$-power degree, which we will do by induction:

Suppose $L=K_1K_2$, and that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are each Galois of $p$-power order over $K$. Then $L$ is also Galois (why?).

Now consider the lattice of fields containing $L$, $K_1$, $K_2$, and $K_1\cap K_2$. This corresponds to a lattice of Galois groups over $K_1\cap K_2$.

Now $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K_1)$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K_2)$ generate $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K_1\cap K_2)$, and they are both normal and disjoint in $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K_1\cap K_2)$ (why?). So you have a direct product, and $[L:K_1\cap K_2]$ is of $p$-power order. It follows that $[L:K]$ is too.

Comment: How do I know that the generator lives in A finite Galois extension? I know that it lives in the compositum of a finite number of finite Galois extensions!

Comment: Well, what is the compositum? It's the set of elements that can be obtained from elements of these finite extensions. So you just have to show, by induction, that if you take the compositum of two finite Galois extensions of $p$-power order, the compositum is again of $p$-power order (and so is its Galois closure)

Comment: But why is its degree a power of $p$? In general the compositum doesn't work well with degrees.

Comment: Yes, there's some work to be done here, but the fact that the subextensions are Galois means it will work out. Give me a few minutes and I'll sketch out something more complete.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Finally managed to solve this. However, in the last paragraph of your answer, are those two subgroups the ones who generate the Galois group? Isn't it generated by the automorphisms of $\mathbb{E}_1$ and $\mathbb{E}_2$ fixing the intersection?

Comment: @AngeloRendina By $E_i$, do you mean what I called $K_i$? If so, automorphisms of the $E_i$ are not subgroups but quotient groups. So it should be correct as I originally wrote it.

Comment: Yes sorry, i meant those. What about the morphism $Gal(L/E_1\cap E_2)\to Gal(E_1/E_1\cap E_2)\times Gal(E_2/E_1\cap E_2), \sigma\mapsto (\sigma|_{E_1},\sigma|_{E_2})$?

Comment: It's an isomorphism.

Comment: That's what I was talking about. Thanks so much!